# What does Polygon2D's polygons property do?

Tags: 2d, godot

Godot [`Polygon2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_polygon2d.html) class has a [`polygons`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_polygon2d.html#class-polygon2d-property-polygons) property of type `Array`. The documentation -at the time of writing- does not say what it does. Adding something to it makes the `Polygon2D` disappear. *Which I would find hard to believe to be the purpose of this property, not only an `Array` is excessive, but we have `visible` for that.*

I have found a question on reddit: [What does a polygon2D's polygons property do?](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/embjs4/what_does_a_polygon2ds_polygons_property_do/) Which has a single reply saying -among other things- that "it doesn't really do anything".

Is it true that it doesn't really do anything? If it does something, what does `Polygon2D`'s `polygons` actually property do?

---

*And I can't reply on an archived question on Reddit, so I'm answering here. Yes, this is me answering my own question. again.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we venture down to the Godot source code, on `Polygon_2d.cpp` we find how `polygons` is used ([here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/master/scene/2d/polygon_2d.cpp#L316)).

Godot expects the array to contain arrays of integers. Reading the code we can also figure out that they are indexes (0 based) for the points.

So, let us try that. We create a `Polygon2D` on the editor, give it a set of points, and then in the `polygons` property we add `PoolIntArray` elements (Using a regular `Array` and adding `int` values also works). On each we add the indexes for the points.

Here I placed points in a grid, and created a couple polygons using the `polygons` property:

[image: Result]

*I placed the odd rows are left to right, and even rows are right to left, just because it was easy.*

As we can see the single `Polygon2D` node is capable of representing multiple polygons created from the same set of points. The `polygons` property of `Polygon2D` specifies the lists of indexes that make up those polygons. That's what the `Polygon2D`'s `polygons` property does.

When we set something to it, the `Polygon2D` disappears because it will not longer create a single polygon loopings the points in the `polygon` property. Instead the `polygons` property specifies the indexes for the points to create multiple polygons. And, of course, setting anything invalid results in nothing visible.

---

It is worth noting that the property is just specified as "Array". The type system does not tell an array of what (it is `Variant`, actually). And the editor will let you add elements to the `Array` that are not valid for this property. Which fails silently (there is no warning or error message).

However, if I add valid arrays of integers, and in them I set negative number, I get an error.

---

Also worth noting is that they are actually drawn as separate polygons. Here I have made some overlapping polygons and gave them some alpha transparency:

[image: Result]

*I used alpha on the `Polygon2D` color for that screenshot. However, using alpha on modulate has the same result.*

As you can see the overlapping area appears more opaque.